# Where can I find flash player installer for the HP Touchpad emulator?

Tags: flash, webos, touchpad

I tried using the Software manager, but it never leaves the loading screen on the emulator.  I can't find an ipk package file either to install via the palm-install command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash isn't currently supported on the emulator.

Comment: Yes, the only build of Flash we can distribute is an in-ROM ARM version.  The emulator runs as a x86 virtual machine, so there's no Flash implementation there.